# Comparing arrays and printing a symbol for each equal element

Tags: arrays, ruby

I want to compare two arrays `A` and `B`, for example:

```
A = [3,1,4,5]
B = [3,6,4,1]
```

and print out a symbol `'^'` (array `B`) for matching elements, and `'+'` for matching elements that are further at the same index position as the other array (array `A`). The output should be something like:

```
+ +^
```

Comment: What should be output for `A = [3,1,1], B = [3,2,1]`?

Comment: It should be:       +^+

Comment: That contradicts the initial condition. Element of `B` in position 1 (`2`) is not appearing in `A`.

Comment: My bad, I'm always confusing myself. Has to be: "+ +" of course

Comment: What do you expect for `A = [1,2,3,4]; B = [2,2,2,2]`?

Comment: looks like you are trying do to a mastermind game https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mastermind_(board_game), it will be easier to answer if you tell us what you are trying to do (https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Answer (score 2):

There are *many* ways to do this in ruby. It's a very flexible and expressive language. Here are a few:

```
A = [3,1,4,5]
B = [3,6,4,1]

# 1.
puts(
  B.map.with_index do |b_item, index|
    if A[index] == b_item
      '+'
    elsif A.include?(b_item)
      '^'
    else
      ' '
    end
  end.join
)

# 2.
B.each_with_index do |b_item, index|
  print(
    if A[index] == b_item
      '+'
    elsif A.include?(b_item)
      '^'
    else
      ' '
    end
  )
end

# 3.
puts(
  A.zip(B).map do |a_item, b_item|
    if a_item == b_item
      '+'
    elsif A.include?(b_item)
      '^'
    else
      ' '
    end
  end.join
)
```

Some minor notes:

- You should probably move this logic into a separate method, and then only `puts`/`print` the result of that method call. This would make the `puts`/`print` look less out of place, and allow you to use the result for other things.
- Solution `#2` is slightly different in that no newline is printed at the end. (You didn't specify this in the question?)

Personally, I'd go with the first approach as it's easiest to understand at a glance.

Comment: I only understood the question after reading this answer. It reads very well.

Answer (score 0):

```
B.map.with_index do |e, i|
  next '+' if A[i] == e
  A.index(e) ? '^' : ' '
end.join
```

Comment: Updated an answer accordingly to the last comment of OP.